# Looking for DNS server software that offers a function like myip.opendns.com

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-ip

OpenDNS has a resource record setup so if you request that record it will return the IP address ([ref](http://www.opendns.com/support/article/224)).

So you can use a command like this `host myip.opendns.com 208.67.222.222` and the result you will get will be the IP address of computer you are using, or the public address used by the NAT you are behind.

What I would like to know is if there are any open source DNS servers that can perform this function as well.

Comment: Warning, a DNS-based solution may give you the IP address of your resolver, not of your computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com) and the "[pipe](http://doc.powerdns.com/backends-detail.html)" backend?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't aware that.  That looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin in my [evldns](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/) framework that can do this.

The [chaos](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/source/browse/trunk/chaos.c) demo will answer for queries for `client.bind` with the client's IP address, in either `A`, `AAAA` or `TXT` format as applicable.

Answer (score 1):

That's a non-standard RR.  If you want to do something more-or-less portable, take a look at the STUN protocol.  It's pretty ghastly but at least it's standard and was designed specifically for the purpose of allowing a host to discover its own IP address and port, as seen by a STUN server.  There are public STUN servers available, listed here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN.  The same web page has pointers to client libraries and server software.

The advantage of the DNS-based approach is that you can use tools you've already got.  But because it's non-standard it's not portable.

Comment: A A or AAAA RR cannot be considered as "non standard".

Comment: +1 for STUN, though, which is indeed the proper solution.